# Mysterious Django API Behavior In Production

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Long time reader but newly joined the community. I have a mysterious issue that I would like to seek help with. Since this is a part of the code that is currently running in production I need to redact parts of the info and will provide information is and when required. If needed I will also make a new sample code to make sure we can all test and also guide me the right way to troubleshoot the issue.

Currently, there is an web application ( django/wagtail/coderedcms ) backend that need to be converted into a mobile app. To allow the mobile app to communicate with the Backend server, I have implemented an API endpoint using the Django-rest-framework. To authenticate the user, I have already implemented a simple authentication endpoint using Django-rest-simplejwt. This part is working fine. One of the requirement for the app is that the user must be able to view/update their profile through the mobile app.

When working in dev server in my localhost, The behaviour is as intended, each user may login using the application, the backend will send back a token, and the tokan will be use subsequently to access the various part off the application.

When the same codebase is being implemented in production( currently in UAT stage) one behaviour that is found, If multiple user is logged in at the same time, The server will only return the profile of the first user that request the profile.
meaning :
user A logged in ....
user B logged in ....
user B request to view his profile ( profile B is shown)
user A request to view his profile ( profile B is shown) <- correct behaviour should be Profile A is shown

This baffled me as during testing on localhost, the behavior are:
user A logged in ....
user B logged in ....
user B request to view his profile ( profile B is shown)
user A request to view his profile ( profile A is shown)

I dont know if this is due to docker, nginx or the django production setting.
However, now I can only narrow down to Nginx and docker as I am using the same configuration in localhost beside the debug=true status.

Any help or pointer would be useful.

I thank you in advance for all that read and answer this silly but mysterious question

Sincerely,
Ashraf

Edit

In reply to Ogulcan Olguner

from production server Postman wield this in the header responds

```
allow →GET, POST, OPTIONS
cache-control →max-age=300
connection →keep-alive
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →application/json
date →Wed, 25 Nov 2020 20:59:03 GMT
expires →Wed, 25 Nov 2020 21:03:30 GMT
server →nginx/1.17.4
strict-transport-security →max-age=31536000
transfer-encoding →chunked
vary →Accept, Origin, Cookie
x-cdn →Incapsula
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →ALLOWALL
x-iinfo →4-22327133-22328885 NNYN CT(2 2 0) RT(1606337880159 62932) q(0 0 0 -1) r(1 1) U16
x-wagtail-cache →hit
```

for LocalHost

```
allow →POST, GET, OPTIONS
content-length →204
content-type →application/json
date →Wed, 25 Nov 2020 20:57:45 GMT
server →WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.5
vary →Accept, Origin
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →DENY
```

Comment: sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: Thanks I think so too

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing since there is not much information about why the error could be caused. If you are not running a separate cache system in production (such as Redis), this error may be caused by the client. Have you tried the same scenario with a tool like Postman?

Comment: Please refer to my edit on the original post for postman
also I dont use a seperate cache system

Comment: Are you sure you have Nginx running locally? WSGI appears as the web server in the request sent to localhost. If there is any cache setting in your Nginx it might be relevant. If you are not managing the locations in the project with Nginx one by one, I recommend that you set the public and private cache settings in Django instead of Nginx. [Django cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/)